# Что такое kotlinx?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx

Часто вижу в коде kotlin на GitHub и в Android Studio инструкцию вида "import kotlinx. ...". что это за kotlinx? (в гугле не нашел)

Comment: kotlin или kotlinx? kotlinx -- `A kotlinx.html library provides DSL to build HTML to Writer/Appendable or DOM at JVM and browser (or other JavaScript engine) for better Kotlin programming for Web.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный импорт используется плагином [Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), который служит для более удобной работы с View элементами из xml файлов

Comment: а, то есть это лишь для андроида? Спасибо!

Comment: Плагин kotlinx-android-extensions уже [устарел](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65179275). Теперь есть [kotlin-parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize). А вместо synthetic можно использовать [view-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).

Answer (score 2):

Пакет `kotlinx` используется для различных расширений (*eXtensions*) языка и библиотек.
Для Android самым популярным расширением является *Android Extensions*.
Есть еще расширения для *coroutines* и *web*, возможно будут и другие.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains под пакетом `kotlinx` публикует официальные библиотеки для Kotlin.

Большинство этих библиотек рассчитаны работать на любой платформе, в которую умеет компилироваться Kotiln. Среди самых популярных библиотек — это [kotlinx.coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html) и [kotlinx.serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html). При этом веб-клиент и сервер [ktor](https://ktor.io/) по какой-то причине не находится под пакетом kotlinx.

Другие примеры библиотек kotlinx можно [найти](https://github.com/orgs/Kotlin/repositories?q=kotlinx&sort=stargazers) на гитхабе: [kotlinx.html](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html), [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime), [kotlinx-io](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io).

Кроме этого, есть Gradle-плагин [kotlin-parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) для Андроид (бывший [kotlin-android-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65179275)). На данный момент этот плагин поддерживается компанией Google и тоже имеет пакет kotlinx.